# Return _id to client on insert in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Whats the best way to retrieve the _id of the data thats JUST been inserted into a collection to the client. I'm trying to redirect on submit with FlowRouter.go("/:_id") but there is no way of retrieving the current id.

```
Meteor.methods ({
    insertData: function(data) { 
        Events.insert(data);
// somehow return this insert's _id to client
    }
});
```

What is the best way of retrieving this data on the client side as soon as its submitted into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server:

```
Meteor.methods ({
    insertData: function(data) { 
      return Events.insert(data);
    }
});
```

Client:

```
  Meteor.call('insertData', (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.reason);
      } else if (response) {
        console.log("ID: ", response);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, this is not working for me, as `Events.insert(data);` returns an `Observable<string>`. Any idea how to solve this @Gemmi? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SoS Could You be more specific? Give an example code :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040730/ionic2-meteor-get-id-of-new-inserted-item?noredirect=1#comment69291771_41040730