# Ionic2 + Meteor: get _id of new inserted item

Tags: mongodb, meteor, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm in an *Ionic2* project with a *Meteor* Database. When I insert a new Item to the database I would need to get the newly generated `_id`. But I don't know how to access the `Observable` in the right way.

Server:

```
newItem() {
   if (!this.userId)
     throw new Meteor.Error('unauthorized', 'User must be logged-in to insert an item');

   return Items.insert({ ownerId: this.userId, title: 'New Item' });
}
```

Client:

```
MeteorObservable.call('newItem').subscribe({

  next: () => {
    //get _id 
  },

  error: (e: Error) => {
    console.log("Error: " + e);
  }

});
```

`Items.insert` returns an `Observable<string>` containing the inserted `_id`. How can I access this `_id` within `next: ()` on client side?

**Edit:**
I also tried this on the client:

```
MeteorObservable.call('newItem').subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error => {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  }
);
```

But there `data` is an empty Object `Object {_isScalar: false}`. :(

**Edit2:**
I also posted it here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/get--id-after-insert-from-returned-observable-on-client/32106

Comment: is this `next: () => {}` something from Meteor? Or ionic?

Comment: usually you'd call `.subscribe(data => { console.log("id: " + data); }, error => { console.log("Error: " + error); }});`

Comment: The `next:`is from their tutorial: https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/chats-mutations
I tried something similar to your code already, but I'll try again

Comment: the `data` in your code is an empty `Object {_isScalar: false}` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was on the server-side:

`Items.collection.insert(...)`

With the added `.collection` it's returning the new `_id`-string.

Comment: why do you need to use raw collection? You should able to use without collection as well.

Comment: Without the collection it's not returning the _id.